# How to change the font for math

Tags: math-mode, fonts

For my thesis I use the `fourier` font because I like it as my main font but I have one problem with it: I do not like the font that `fourier` uses for math. How can I change/override this?
I just want the `default` font for math that tex uses, in my whole document...

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

% Font fourier
\usepackage{fourier}

% Try to override it
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}%  for math
%\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
```

Comment: Don't do that! They don't match well and your document will look horrible. Either use fourier for text and math (you may use `erewhon` for text, which is a  clone/extension of `Adobe Utopia`, on which Fourier is based). Or use Computer Modern (the default) or Latin Modern if you need accented letters.

Comment: So because I do not like the `\mathcal` math letters of `fourier` I need to change the font for my whole thesis?

Comment: That's another problem: you always can change a math alphabet. I don't think it's a problem for `\mathcal`. Just check the thickness of the stroke is compatible. You also can try Zapf Chancery or its URW clone.

Comment: Hi Gerjan, [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Done, I have updated my post

Answer (score 5):

You can easily obtain a horrible document mixing Utopia as text font and Palatino (`mathpazo`) for math by doing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{put}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext} % just to produce mock text

\begin{document}

\blindmathtrue
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even more appalling is when Computer Modern is used for math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{put}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindmathtrue
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the same with `fourier`:

[image]

Take your pick, but be aware of the following advices

1. ***never*** load other math font packages along with `fourier`, because this package sets up different encodings for the math font and you easily get wrong symbols
2. ***never*** mix different fonts for text and math

Comment: *never mix different fonts for text and math* So you advise to use separate fonts...? Any particular reason?

Comment: @hola Sorry, but I don’t understand.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Is there any particular reason you advise not to mix different fonts for text and math?

Comment: @hola One could use *very* different fonts, I’m thinking to Euler for math. To the contrary, Times for text and Computer Modern for math make one’s eyes bleed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using:

```
% Font fourier
\usepackage{fourier} 

% Only use the math font of mathpazo
\let\temp\rmdefault
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\let\rmdefault\temp
```

Comment: Seems to work for me

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is change the font you get with `\mathcal` (and I agree that in `fourier` the cal fonts are not well readable) do this

```
\usepackage{fourier}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```